# Java/Kotlin MongoDB search without counting

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, search

I need to search for objects using `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` and `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`.

I implemented a search with getting the number of objects each time. This is not very optimal, as I understand it.

```kotlin
fun search(query: Query, pageable: Pageable): Page<BookDocument> {
    val bookObjects = mongoTemplate.find(
        query.with(pageable),
        BookDocument::class.java
    )
    val count = mongoTemplate.count(query, BookDocument::class.java)
    return PageImpl(bookObjects, pageable, count)
}
```

Is it possible to implement a search without counting?

Actually my function should return such `PageDto`. But I don't know how it can be most optimally implemented.

```kotlin
class PageDto<T>(
    val pageable: Pageable,
    val data: List<T>,
    val hasNext: Boolean,
    val hasPrevious: Boolean // optional field
)
```

Comment: are you asking to get count without second query? or are you okay to not have any count in response? just make sure you have correct indexes to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this issue like this:

```kotlin
fun search(query: Query, pageable: Pageable): PageDto<BookDocument> {
     val bookObjects = mongoTemplate.find(query, BookDocument::class.java)
     return PageDto(pageable, bookObjects)
}
```

```kotlin
data class PageDto<T>(
    val pageable: Pageable,
    val content: List<T>,
    val hasNext: Boolean,
    val hasPrevious: Boolean
) {
    constructor(
        pageable: Pageable,
        data: List<T>
    ) : this(
        pageable = pageable,
        content = data.take(pageable.pageSize),
        hasNext = data.count() > pageable.pageSize,
        hasPrevious = pageable.offset > 0
    )
}
```